# graphql server installation has problem when following react+apollo track in howtographql website

Tags: curl, graphql, tar, react-apollo

I am using the curl command to have a graphQL server, I am following docs from the website https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/1-getting-started/

when I am running the command:-

**curl https://codeload.github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/tar.gz/starter | tar -xz --strip=1 react-apollo-starter/server**

for downloading the server code as mentioned in the docs,The error of the above command was in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrSu3.png)

please help to rectify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solved the issue,if you face similar kind of issue refer:https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/issues/85#issuecomment-671262863